# Existence of holomorphic function.

Tags: complex-analysis

How to determine whether for given $a,b,c,d(reals)$  there exists a holomorphic $f:D\to D$ with $f(a)=b$ and
$f ′(c)=d$ , where $D=\{|z|<1\}$.

For example does there exist a holomorphic function $f:D \rightarrow D$ such that $f(3/4)=3/4$ and $f ′(2/3)=3/4$ ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** First consider the special case $f(0)=0$ and $f'(r)=w$ with $r$ a nonnegative real number and $w\in \mathbb C$. Which $r$ and $w$ are possible?

For the general case, observe that you can transfrom $f$ with $f(a)=b$ and $f'(c)=d$ to a function as in the first paragraph. Determine how $r$ and $w$ depend on $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: please explane in details i do not got the point....

Comment: Hold on. I think I was somewhat fixated on the case $a=c$

Comment: take a,b,c,d any real between -1 and 1

Comment: there is no condition on a,b,c,d....any real between -1 and 1

Comment: can schwartz lemma or pick lemma help ?